# my code used to work but then no more after new years eve: request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '6M', close[1])

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

pretty much as title says. it used to work last year but it isn't giving me the correct data anymore for timeframes that need last years data. it happened with the year passing 2023 to 2024.

today(jan 15th) 'D' and 'W' timeframes are working ok **I assume bc they fit in available 2024 data range**. but say.. closing price data for '3M' is wrong

can someone please help fix. It should work across the years. here's the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator('myindicator', overlay=true)
shares = input(22, 'Shares')

close_prev_(p) =>
    sh = shares
    fech = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, p, close[1] * sh)
    res = '\n' + str.format('{0,number,currency}', close * sh - fech) + ' (' + str.tostring((close * sh - fech) / fech * 100, '#.##') + '%) ' + ' [' + p + ']'
    res

l = label.new(bar_index, na, close_prev_('D') + close_prev_('W') + close_prev_('M') + close_prev_('3M') + close_prev_('6M') + close_prev_('12M'), 
  color=close >= open ? color.green : color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

label.delete(l[1])
```

from the docs I was expecting behavior for

```
request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '6M', close[1])
```

should remain as it was within/along 2023.